# How to use a archived version of Ensembl in biomaRt

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am using the `biomaRt` package in R to retrieve chromosomal locations of genes.
I would like to use an archived version of ensemble to do so.

According to the `biomaRt` manual, one should

(1) Ask for available Ensembl archives

```
 listMarts(archive = TRUE)
```

(2) Load the required version (in this case Ensembl 51 mouse genes)

```
useMart("ensembl_mart_51", dataset="mmusculus_gene_ensembl", archive=T)
```

When I run the last command, I get the following error:

```
"Error in read.table(con, sep = "\t", header = FALSE, quote = "", comment.char = "",  : 
  no lines available in input"
```

What is going wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: This question would be better asked of the biomaRt developers directly or at [BioStar](http://www.biostars.org/).

Comment: Can you run the `traceback` function after the error is thrown and see what it says?

Comment: Probably just a temporary glitch, as this seems to work fine now, at least for me. BTW, do you have the latest version of biomaRt?